# facebook post to fan page - PHP to asp.net

Tags: c#, php, .net, asp.net, facebook

I'm new to C# (asp.net) so i need little help.
On this forum I found a PHP, post to fan page wall, code.

Here it is:

```
$facebook->call_api('/(pageID)/feed/', "post",array('message'=>"message here"));
```

Can someone transform this to C# command?

I think that $facebook is probably `facebookapi facebook = new facebookapi();` right?
i just don't know call_api command in C#

Comment: Post a complete reference to the thread. Link or message content

Comment: Uff, I close down, and I can't find it anymore. But the user said that the code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531214/facebook-post-to-fan-page-php-to-asp-net/4531623#4531623) says this is very difficult with so little code, but something like ...

```
var vMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
vMessages.Add("message", "message here");

fbApp.Post('/(pageID)/feed/', vMessages);
```

To create a tree structure of Dictionary:

```
var vData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary>();

var vUser = new Dictionary<string, object>();
vUser.Add("id","40796308305_490173213305");

var vFromUser = new Dictionary<string, object>();
vFromUser.Add("name","Coca-Cola");
vFromUser.Add("category","Company");
vFromUser.Add("category","40796308305");
vUser.Add("from",vFromUser);

vData.Add("User1",vUser);
```

This is a VERY bad way to do this in .NET, the best is probably to create class  and include   IDictionary.
But these are written without testing the API.

Comment: is there any way that you can add your own token into dictionary. And that this token would be added to the page feed even if it doesn't exist.
For example, fb coca cola fan page feed:
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed

Can I add bleble token in there.
In case you know?

Tnx for the post btw

Answer (score 2):

This is one single call from a larger API. It's going to be pointless to try to translate this line into C#: You would have to port the entire library.

You will need to find a Facebook API for C# and use that. For example, there seems to be an official C# SDK [here](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk).

Comment: I already have this sdk, and the facebook library. I was just wondering if... variable can be set from the facebookApi library in all the programing languages, where there is a sdk for it.
But I don't know  call_api() command in C#, or even if the syntax is the same or not.